# react-select unable to paste value in the search field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) library as a search field with handy autosuggest etc. The problem is that the browser does not identify the text input for the select field as a text field which means I cannot paste values in it. Actually `Ctrl + V` works fine but the right-click menu doesn't have a "Paste" option and, more importantly, I cannot long-press paste from the touch version. So the question is how can I let the browser know that it is a text input so it would display the "Paste" option?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4106#issuecomment-743959376

#### TLDR:

```
input: (css) => ({
  ...css,
  /* expand the Input Component div */
  width: "100%",
  
  /* expand the Input Component child div */
  "> div": {
    width: "100%"
   },

  /* expand the Input Component input */
  input: {
    width: "100% !important",
    textAlign: "left"
  }
})
```

You have already an existing `input` element. But `react-select` by default sets the input's width as 2px, that's why each time you want to open context menu with a right mouse click, you just open the regular context menu. Try to set the change width of the input with the code snippet suggested in the issue comment ☝️